# How can I convert this SQL query to an Entity Framework v4.0 query?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

How can I convert this SQL query to an Entity Framework v4.0 query?

```
WITH Sales_CTE (Name, Count1) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000000 
        Name, COUNT(Name) 
    FROM
        Customers 
    WHERE
        subscriptionState != 0
    GROUP BY 
        Name
    HAVING
        COUNT(Name) >= 0
    ORDER BY
        COUNT(Name)
)
SELECT
    COUNT(count1), Count1 
FROM
    Sales_CTE 
GROUP BY
    count1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in EF6:

```
        var sales_cte = from c in db.Customers
                        where c.subscriptionState != 0
                        group c by c.Name into c_byName
                        where c_byName.Count() > 0
                        orderby c_byName.Count()
                        select new { Name = c_byName.Key, Count1 = c_byName.Count() };

        var q = from r in sales_cte.Take(1000000)
                group r by r.Count1 into r_byCount1
                select new { Count = r_byCount1.Count(), Count1=r_byCount1.Key };
```

Translates to

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy2].[K1] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[A3] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (1000000) [GroupBy1].[A3] AS [A3]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Name] AS [K1], 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1], 
                COUNT(1) AS [A2], 
                COUNT(1) AS [A3]
                FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE 0 <> [Extent1].[subscriptionState]
                GROUP BY [Extent1].[Name]
            )  AS [GroupBy1]
            WHERE [GroupBy1].[A1] > 0
            ORDER BY [GroupBy1].[A2] ASC
        )  AS [Limit1]
        GROUP BY [Limit1].[A3]
    )  AS [GroupBy2]
```